# Treating 2 fields as the same across standard objects

Tags: workflow

I have a custom field "next step" in contacts that I want to be able to update when text is entered into the "next step" field in opportunities.  I also want "next step" in opportunities to update when text is entered (or changed) in the "next step" field in contacts.

I've been able to get the update to work one way opp>contact with workflow but not been able to get the fields to act as one like I need to. Should this be a trigger? If so as I have no coding experience can someone possibly help me work out a trigger?  If this can be done purely as a workflow rule can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Progress on trigger, error message of "Loop variable must be of type SOBJECT:Contact"

```
trigger UpdateNextStep on Contact (after insert) {

   List<contact>lstContactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>(); 

   for( opportunity opp : trigger.new) { 

      if(opp.NextStep != null) { 

         contact objCOntact = new Contact(id=opp.NextStep); 
         objContact.Next_Step__c = opp.NextStep; 
         lstContactsToUpdate.add(objContact); 

      } 

   } 

   update lstContactsToUpdate; 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Jesse, Have you created workflow on both Contacts and Opportunity? There's no need for a trigger provided you have workflow that initiates field updates on the respective objects when either one is updated,

Comment: I must be setting up the fields wrong then. I have contact::next_step_c set as lookup to opportunity::nextstep so I can't get it to look up from opportunity to contact.

Comment: I should have caught this the first time around. A look-up only works in one direction, as in a field on Opp looking up the value in a field on Contact. It doesn't work as a 2-way street where one can change the other whenever one object is updated. That functionality would typically require a trigger to make it happen. Two triggers actually; one for each object along with a check for recursion so they don't get caught in an infinite loop where they both keep firing.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've had a few people tell me that workflow would do this but I had yet to find an actual example of it being done that way. Amy advice for a noncoder on how to get a trigger written for this?

Comment: You'll want to start by working through some of the tutorials like the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/). It walks you thru creating your first trigger. Once you've done one, try creating one for this situation & post back with your code and where you encountering problems. The [Force.com workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/) is also a good resource for getting started as it has a trigger example in it too.

Comment: Okay so i have gotten this far but i get "Loop variable must be of type SOBJECT:Contact"                                                                                             trigger UpdateNextStep on Contact (after insert) 

{List<contact>lstContactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
for( opportunity opp : trigger.new)
{
if(opp.NextStep != null)
{
 contact objCOntact = new Contact(id=opp.NextStep);
  objContact.Next_Step__c = opp.NextStep;
 
  lstContactsToUpdate.add(objContact);
}
}

update lstContactsToUpdate;

}

Comment: I've added your code to your post above for you Jesse and will provide an answer to what you're encountering below.

Comment: Thank you,I will remember to update the op next time instead of adding comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the problem with the code as you've written it is that your outer loop operates on the Opportunity Object, but everything inside the loop is trying to operate on the contact object. One way of solving that is to create a collection of the contact Ids to update and the opportunity Id's associated with them.

Now I'm a bit confused by your code as it's currently written. As I understood what you've described, `nextstep__c` is supposed to be a text field in both Opportunity and Contacts. If that's the case, the ContactId cannot be = `opp.nextstep`. I.E there's a problem with this statement both as it's written and it can't contain the relationship you've described:

```
contact objCOntact = new Contact(id=opp.NextStep); // The id cannot be opp.NextStep__c
```

Since `NextStep` has to be a custom field, it also needs to be appended by a `__c` regardless of whether it uses capitalization to make it appear different than `nextstep__c`. Are these two fields supposed to be the same?

I then see where you have:

```
objContact.Next_Step__c = opp.NextStep; // again this must be opp.NextStep__c
```

So my question is, how are you actually identifying the related contact?  If `NextStep` contains comments, it can't be through the text field. If it contains both, then you'll need to parse it to get the ContactId from it first, then update the fields between the two. You'll also need to get the IdvalueOf the text string which Apex normally will handle for you without any problems if it's an 18 character ID, but to be safe, it's a good idea to convert it.

Once you have the field on Opp that contains the ContactId, you can loop through Opp to create a map of Contact IDs and the associated Strings of text which you can easily use to update Contacts with.

It would work something like this:

```
trigger UpdateNextStep on Contact (after insert) {

   List<contact>lstContactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
   Map<Id, String>CtcId2NxtStp = new Map<Id, String>(); 

   for( opportunity opp : trigger.new) { 

      // many things can change in trigger.new. You want to test to see if it's NextStep is one of them
      // and only want to do an update if has changed.

      // you may need to check to see if either opp.NextStep__c and trigger.old.get(opp.Id).NextStep.isEmpty == false 
      // before doing what's below to avoid a null pointer exceptions from being thrown. 

      if(opp.NextStep__c. != trigger.old.get(opp.Id).NextStep  && opp.RelContactId__c != null) { 

         CtcId2NxtStp.put(opp.RelContactId__c, opp.NextStep__c.isEmpty ); 

      }

   }  

   integer n = 0;
   for(Id i : CtcId2NxtStp.keyset){

      lstContactsToUpdate[n].Id = i;
      lstContactsToUpdate[n].Next_Step__c = CtcId2NxtStp.get(i).NextStep__c ;

      n++;      
   }

   update lstContactsToUpdate; 

}
```

Something like the above should work for you once you get your fields sorted out.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I need a lot more reading and practice before I will be able to figure this out though. All I want is the custom contact  field to have the same text as the standard field in opp in real time. Essentially making them the same field just on 2 standard objects. Thank you so much for the help.